# How to name nodes in a graph in the English language?

Tags: .net, oop

I need to define an element from linkedList in a object:

> **A**
>     /    \
>   X      Y

How could I name the entire object and its components in English?

à la: `Hand-Body-Leg` object named `Body`. or maybe somthing like `queue kernel hand` `treeObject`?

Ok, let's show you the example of a railway:

> **NodeStation** => Station => Station =>
>   Station => **NodeStation** => Station =>
>   Station => **NodeStation** => ...

I need to have an object (`NodeStationAndNeighbourdStations`) with following 3 elements: `NodeStation`, `LeftNeighbor`, `RightNeighbor` in a more general manner.

Comment: If you explain the _meaning_ of `A`, `X` and `Y`, we could help with naming.

Comment: I added .NET because its fot that architecture I need names.

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about how they behave? Many names could fit the little info you've given us.

Comment: @serhio - so, each node will have this structure? And what does each part mean? Do the `A`, `X` and `Y` have meaning that is attached to the linked list or meaning that is irrelevant to the linked list?

Comment: @Oded: once declared the object have nothing with the linked list. I have some important elements in the linked List, and some secondary elements in the linked list. I need to extract only "important" elements from this linkedList with its neighbors.

Comment: @serhio - still not clear. Is `X` pointing to another part of the linked list? Does `Y`? Does `A`?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/tree_structure.html and from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Basic_concepts_and_nomenclature

Comment: @serhio - Can you explain how `NodeStation` and `Station` relate to `A`, `X`, `Y` and the object itself?

Comment: @Oded `NodeStation` is `A`; `X` and `Y` are `Station`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the taken solution was

```
ListElement(Previous, Root, Following)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
             Node                        Node
              |                            |
     ------ Parent ------              --- A ---  
     |                  |              |       | 
Left child         Right child         X       Y
```

The whole object I'd call Node.

Comment: Say, A - parent, X, Y left rigth child, and the object?

Comment: The name is Node. You'd have: Node's parent, parent's left and right child.

Comment: Say, the parent is not really a parent, like in inheritance or WinForms... :) it's just the "main" node, and auxiliary nodes.

Comment: So, say... as real object names this could be `Node` containing: `Left`, `Right` and `Root`...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the kind of naming you mean - a *node* that consists of:

```
A - parent/head
X - left child/node
Y - right child/node
```

Comment: A `Node` with `Parent`, `LeftChild` and `RightChild`? maybe... but as I said, this should not be linked to the list, anymore. So maybe not Node...

Comment: @serhio - A `Node` in the linked list then.

Answer (score 1):

Are X and Y children of A?  That is what many will infer from your diagram.  If instead A,X, and Y are merely strings then you have 3 fields that could be within some class name.  The question is what are the slashes supposed to imply is where I think 99% of the problem is here.

---

Given the edits to the question, I'm thinking that the other ideas of this being a binary tree are correct where A, X, and Y are all Nodes of the tree, where A is the Root, with X as its Left Child, Y as its Right Child and the whole structure called a Binary Tree, assuming that there are only 2 children allowed per node.  If there can be any number of children then this is a different structure.  However, this isn't a Linked List to my mind in the traditional sense as usually a linked list is depicted in linear terms,e.g. A->X->Y so that each node is only pointing at one node, with the anomaly of a doubly-linked list being separate as usually a linked list is a singly-linked list to my mind.

---

I'm still confused by what that picture is supposed to imply.  If someone is at A, do they see X and Y, while at X or Y they only see A?  Are all three elements of a class and the diagram isn't useful as there isn't a point in displaying them this way?  Would there be other elements that may contain X or Y as the parent node or is it that each node in the tree contains 3 elements like A,X,Y and there isn't any connection among the elements?  This is a very confusing picture as this isn't looking like many other graph-like structures I've seen.

---

So, A is a NodeStation and each of X and Y are Stations.  Thus, each is a separate element of the list?  Perhaps a better way to display this would be

```
... => X <=> A <=> Y <=...
```

Though even that has some challenges to it, in terms of understanding what is and isn't implied.

Comment: as I already said in a comment this is not a three, because it contains always exactly 3 elements, no less or more. But the "Root" keyword for the main Node is a good choice.

Comment: "Would there be other elements that may contain X or Y". You complicate the things. I separate 3 and only 3, never less or more, so, 3 elements from a path. An element is a Station(X, Y) or a NodeStation(:Station, for A). By NodeStation, I mean a station that can acquire multiple trains, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean (or even if this question is supposed to be on stackoverflow) but
wouldn't you just call it the Tree, the left node and the right node ?

Comment: This is not a three, because have always 3 elements, A, X, Y

Answer (score 0):

```
parent -> child
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It's a **link** really. Like a link in a chain. Hence linked list.

Comment: A link, before me, should *link* something. This is more about the order, or position of X and Y vs the A.